# react js Añadir espacio tabulado

Tags: reactjs, jsx

tengo la siguiente linea:

```
<div className="col-md-10">                
    { tab + item.name} 
</div>
```

se trata de una parte de una función recursiva, la cual imprime sus hijos de cada padre, la cuestion es que en la variable tab va hacer igual a (tab + `\t`) cada vez de llame de forma recursiva a la funcion, algo como esto:

```
(tab + `\t`)
```

y la funcion la tengo declara como:

```
function list(data, tab){
.
.
    data.map( item => {
     .
     .
    <div className="col-md-10">                
        { tab + item.name} 
    </div>
    .
    .
    )
.
.
}
```

estoy obteniendo esto como resultado:

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
```

y quiero algo como:

```
name 1
      name 2
            name 3
```

realice una prueba por medio de la consola, imprimiendo tab y alli si esta tabulando cada nombre, pero al verlo en la vista de la lista no se esta tabulando, a que se debera esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema puede estar en que `html` no reconoce los espacios, una forma para que `html` te reconozca los espacios es con `\u00A0` esto es igual a 1 espacio en blanco.

por lo tanto puedes tener tu `tab` declarada con los espacios

```
const tab = '\u00A0';
```

Otra forma de colocar `tab` coloca los 4 espacios en blanco que contiene un `tab` usando `&nbsp;`.
Lo declaramos de la siguiente manera para evitar errores.

```
const tab = <>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</>;
```

Una ves declarado lo podemos utilizar, un ejemplo de su uso es el siguiente.

```
<p>texto con un tab{tab}para separar texto</p>
```

Comment: no me reconocio el "&nbsp;" da error, es extraño, use este ''\u00A0" y si me funciona.... Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @Gerarca, Que error te marco ?

Comment: @Gerarca, ok es bueno que hayas logrado resolver el problema, por favor agrega tu como respuesta el como lo solucionaste y aceptarla como correcta o igual puedes editar mi respuesta para cambiar lo que si te funciono.
Cualquiera de las opciones es valida, para ayudar a otros a resolver el mismo problema o similares.

Comment: al usar &nbsp da el error "Unexpected token"    revisa este ejemplo https://codesandbox.io/s/2ozywv8knj

Comment: @Gerarca ya veo el error, debí especificar un poco mejor el como utilizarlo y olvide probar el código pensando que funcionaría.

Comment: @Gerarca funciona de forma correcta utilizada de esta manera 
`<h2>Start editing to see&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;some magic happen!</h2>`
Por si aun te sirve lo puedes utilizar, realizare pruebas directas en un compilador y mejorare la respuesta.